# Wait for a function to finish, before the next one executes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I have a react app. In it when a user summits the form, I want to open a modal, and store the users response in state. Based on this reponse I want to preform some business logic, then post the form.

This is my onsubmit method

```
      async function onSubmit(submission: IPayload) {
        await handleModal();
        await submit(submission);
      }
    
      async function submit(submission: ICreateAdPayload) {
          await api.create({ this is where all the props go})
      }

     // Heres I set the state of the modal to open, which then chanes the open prop on another component for the modal to open.

      async function handleModal(submission: any) {
        setShowModal(true);
    
        // handle logic

        setShowModal(false);
  }
```

However my submit function is being carried out as soon as the modal opens. Any idea?

Comment: Whatever code is in `// handle logic` will need to be modified to create a promise, and then you need to await that promise. Without knowing what that code is, there's no way for me to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to `await handleModal(...)` then that method must return a `Promise` which you `resolve` when it's work has finished - assuming it itself does not need to `await` anything, it does NOT need  to be marked `async`

```
function handleModal(submission: any) {
    setShowModal(true);

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        // handle logic 

        setShowModal(false);

        resolve();
    });
}
```